# Active Directory Membership Provider - how to expand on this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I'm working on getting an MVC app up and running via AD Membership Provider and I'm having some issues figuring this out. I have a base configuration setup and working when I login as foo@my.domain.com + password.

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnString" connectionString="LDAP://domaincontroller/OU=Product Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" />
   </connectionStrings>

  <membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
     <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnString"
             connectionUsername="my.domain.com\service_account"
             connectionPassword="biguglypassword"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     </providers>
  </membership>
```

However, I'd LIKE to do some other things and I'm not sure how to go about them.

1. Login without typing the domain (i.e. the "@my.domain.com"). I realize that this could only work if I limit myself to just one domain - that's fine.
2. Organize users in up to N different OUs within a single OU. As you can tell from my current connection string, I'm authenticating users in my `Product Users` OU. I would LIKE to create OUs for various companies within this OU and put the users into those OUs. How can I authenticate across all of these different OUs?
3. I'm trying to figure out how the Active Directory Membership Provider ties in with the Profile and Role providers. Are there AD versions of those too or am I stuck with SQL, home-grown, or finding something somebody else has coded up?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to point 3:

I answered a similar question about this a while back: ["How can i implement a role-hierarchy in an asp.net mvc app using activedirectorymembershipprovider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756299/how-can-i-implement-a-role-hierarchy-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app-using-activedirectorym/758469#758469).

There is the [WindowsTokenRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx) that should provide you with details of the Users roles from AD - it's a read-only provider, and only provides methods for `IsUserInRole` and `GetRolesForUser`, but may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Hmm, that codeplex project seems abandoned and has no releases available for download. Could have some useful code, but I'm not sure I want to blindly take that and use it in production. The codeproject.com option looks more viable. I think my answer is going to be "let's try not to use AD for this", if possible. Or if I do, then use it for a simple scenario and nothing too complex. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I prefer it as source rather than a release that I can "blindly take and use in production" ;) At least that way I'll probably actually give the code a quick once over, whereas with a dll I might not open up reflector to see what's going on inside unless I can't work out how to use it :(

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I don't want to home-brew everything we use. It sure is nice to be able to buy maintained products and just depend on them. Additionally, I'm just not sure how valuable it is for me to ramp up and learn what I need to learn in order to determine if that source is good or not. After all, AD is by far NOT my expertise and learning it is not the most exciting idea I've ever had...

Comment: I totally agree with the buy not rewrite option - and yes often it's better to let someone else get into the nitty gritty of the details :) That said, it might not be exciting, but looking around, it might be a valuable skill to have ;)

Comment: Pretty much any skill is valuable to have. This one, however, is very far down on the totem pole on my value system. ;-)

Comment: It is incorrect to claim that MS did not supply a Role Provider that uses AD. They do, and it is called the WindowsTokenRoleProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For item #1, I found my answer. I need to add `attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"`

```
    <add name="MyProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnString"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
         connectionUsername="my.domain.com\service_account"
         connectionPassword="biguglypassword"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to point 2:

I had the same problem, so what I did was remove the OU from the connection string.
Something like this:

```
<add name="MyConnString" connectionString="LDAP://domaincontroller/DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" />
```

Now, I can authenticate users across all of these different OUs.